# Including a signature image in scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, letters

Hi there: I have a letter template using scrlttr2 and I am trying to insert a signature image.  I was using the code posted here [texblog](http://texblog.org/2010/05/04/latex-letter-signature-as-image/) and it sort of works.  It throws an undefined sequence error, but, if you force the compilation through to the end, it actually produces a document that looks like what it is supposed to.  What can I do to improve this? MWE is below. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, UScommercial9,paper=letter]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[space]{grffile} %This is necessary because the fromlogo is on a     drive with spaces in its path name
\KOMAoptions{fromlogo=on}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-golden}} %In my code, this is a link to my company's logo

\renewcommand{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright} % make the signature ragged right
\setkomavar{subject}{Test}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Address\\
City\\
Province
}

\opening{To Whom It May Concern}  

\blindtext

\closing{Yours truly,\\
\fromsig{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-golden}}\\ %In my code this is a link to my signature file
\fromname{My name}
} %eg. Regards

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: I made a mistake and corrected it below.

Answer (score 17):

The answer is that this section of the code:

```
\closing{Yours truly,\\
\fromsig{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-golden}}\\ %In my code this is a link to my signature file
\fromname{My name}
} %eg. Regards
```

actually implies the letter class, not the KOMA-script. I was mixing classes.
This works:

```
%insert the following in the preamble
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-golden}\\\usekomavar{fromname}} 
%write the signature as follows 
\closing{Yours truly}
```

Comment: Now: I realize that I can't find a way to put the logo at the center of the page, rather than on the right.  Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: You could use the KOMA variable `firsthead` to layout your own header on the first page: `\setkomavar{firsthead}{\centering\usekomavar{fromlogo}}`. Then the line `\KOMAoptions{fromlogo=on}` has no effect and could be removed. If that does not solve the problem in your comment please ask a new question.